# Regular Expression for if statement

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I want to make a check that will check the data inside a text field on a website. The data in the text field needs to start with one of the following words:

- Voornaam
- Achternaam
- Expertise
- Punten
- AantalStemmen
- GemiddeldePunten
- Achievements

It must then be followed by a if statement symbol: `==` or `>=` or `<=` and then a number or text. I can't get it to work. Does anybody know how to make a regular expression with this much requirements and an if statement symbol.

Comment: What did you try ? BTW it would be cleaner to not use only a regex.

Comment: i tried to make an regular expression on http://regexr.com/ but failed on the first attempt to make the first word be the same as the list from above :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
^(?:Voornaam|Achternaam|Expertise|Punten|AantalStemmen|GemiddeldePunten|Achievements)(==|>=|<=)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/oK5oB6

Comment: This literally answers but OP should probably parse then check against an array.